# How can I save a distance computed with geopy in an array?

Tags: python, loops, distance, geopy, coords

I am usingn geopy and I want to save the computed distance in an array. Here is what I tried so far:

```
import geopy.distance
for i in dfP.itertuples():
    coords_1 = (-20.91, 144.3517)
     
    coords_2 = (i.Latitude, i.Longitude)  #(-20.51, 144.3517)
    dist = geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km
    print(dist)
```

Comment: And why is your solution not working? How does your solution differ from what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy arrays.
import numpy and define your variable dist as numpy array as follows.

```
import numpy as np

dist=np.array(dist)
```

and change dist to dist[i] in your code.

```
dist[i] = geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can define an empty list and append each value.
your code would be as follows:

```
import geopy.distance

dist = []
for i in dfP.itertuples():
    coords_1 = (-20.91, 144.3517)
     
    coords_2 = (i.Latitude, i.Longitude)  #(-20.51, 144.3517)
    dist.append(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)
print(dist)
```

Comment: it works perfect thanks the only thing is that Print(dist) has to be out of the for loop